# How to read Automatic Proxy Detection (WPAD) in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

in asp.net we can use the following setting in web.config to point to a wpad.dat file to read all the proxy setting, is there a way we can achieve the same thing in asp.net core?

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy autoDetect="True" scriptLocation="http://wpad.dat" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32135 You already got answers from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes,  but looks like using the IE setting is the only way , thank you